# Some appilications auto start itself repeatedly after login

Tags: startup, kubuntu

Every time I start my Kubuntu system (10.10) after I login it starts up several instances of certain applications (first it was terminal, now it is krusader) and increase the number of instances with each login (now it starts more than 15~ times)..

I have looked at System settings -> Startup and shutdown section , but I haven't found anything in there.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get 15 instances of applications, but you've most likely set the setting "On Login" setting to "Restore previous session" which is the default.

Change it to "Start with an empty session" and applications from previous sessions won't be started again.

The location is marked with a red circle in the screenshot below.

[image: System Settings -- Session management]